# Clear contents from selected rows based on header

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to have a macro that deletes a range of rows in specific columns based on the column headers. More specifically, let's say any column that is labeled 'C' at row 5, I'd like to clear the contents of rows 11 through 33 for those specific columns by looping through columns B thru CB (for example). Thank you!

Sample:

```
Sub Hide_Columns_Containing_Value()
'Description: This macro will loop through a row and
'hide the column if the cell in row 1 of the column
'has the value of C.
'Author: Jon Acampora, Excel Campus

Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("A5:CE5").Cells
        If c.Value = "C" Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True  {{{<------would like to clear contents of rows 11 thru 33 instead of hide columns}}}


        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help you to improve your question. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, understood. I just posted what I was trying to modify to complete the necessary task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options, here's one using `Intersect`:

```
 Intersect(c.EntireColumn, Rows("11:33")).ClearContents
```